# How do you create a variable of scope EnvVariable?

Tags: ssis, bids

How do you create a variable of scope EnvVariable as shown in this screenshot

[image: Screenshot 2]

of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180378/ssis-best-practices-when-handling-files-can-i-go-configless) StackOverflow Answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope usually represents the `Package` name or a `Control Flow task` name. Here in this case, `EnvVariable` represents the package name. Refer screenshot #**4**. To create a variable, follow the below mentioned steps.

1. Right-click on the package and select `Variables`. Refer screenshot #**1**.
2. On the `Variables` pane, click the first icon to create a variable. Refer screenshot #**2**.
3. By default, the variable will be named `Variable`. Change the name to **FilePath**.
4. By default, the variable data type will be `Int32`. Change the data type to **String**.
5. You can also access the Variables pane from `SSIS` menu --> `Variables`. Make sure that you click on the package. Otherwise, the options won't be visible. Refer screenshot #**3**.

Hope that helps.

**Screenshot #1:**

[image: 1]

**Screenshot #2:**

[image: 2]

**Screenshot #3:**

[image: 3]

**Screenshot #4:**

[image: 4]

Comment: My bad. If I had any experience with this, it wouldn've been obvious. ty!